# MySQL 5.6 information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS inconsistency

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-5.6

I'm building the Docker image with MySQL 5.6 inside (for tests/CI purposes only) and creates the schema and all the tables and then commit the docker container as an image. I intentionally remap the DATADIR to a specific location to keep it inside the container, and not on the volume.

Base image is `mysql/mysql-server:5.6`

I noticed this super strange behavior:

Every time I start the container and make the following query for the first time:

```
select * from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

I see something like:

```
+-----+------------------------+-----+
| ... | UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME | ... |
+-----+------------------------+-----+
|     | NULL                   |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | NULL                   |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | NULL                   |     |
```

But if I call it again straight away I see

```
+-----+------------------------+-----+
| ... | UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME | ... |
+-----+------------------------+-----+
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
|     | PRIMARY                |     |
```

So after first call some of the constraints with initially NULL values became "initialised" somehow.

The code of creating these foreign keys is similar so have no idea why some of them have NULLs and some don't.

`...FOREIGN KEY (campaign) REFERENCES coupon_campaign(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,...`

Why it might harm? I use JOOQ and want to do a jooq-codegen on the created container. And because JOOQ uses this system tables to describe the data structure it produces inconsistent results.

Could somebody please hint why this might happen?